# Ignoring an output parameter from vDSP

Tags: swift, vdsp

When using vDSP to perform some speedy calculations, I often don't care about one of the output parameters. Let's say I'm finding the index of an array's maximum value:

```
var m:Float = 0
var i:vDSP_Length = 0
vDSP_maxvi(&array,
           1,
           &m,
           &i,
           vDSP_Length(array.count))
```

Ideally, I'd like to get rid of `m` altogether so that `vDSP_maxvi` fills `i` only. Something like:

```
var i:vDSP_Length = 0
vDSP_maxvi(&array,
           1,
           nil,
           &i,
           vDSP_Length(array.count))
```

But of course this doesn't work (*"nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>'"*). Is there some sort of argument I can send to these kinds of methods that says "ignore this parameter"? Thanks for reading.

Comment: What's the harm in just creating a local var and ignoring its value? if it's just for the sake of code cleanliness, you could create a wrapper function omitting the argument.

Comment: All vDSP functions expect non-NULL for their pointer arguments unless otherwise noted.

Comment: @ConnorNeville It's more of a speed optimization for cases where I need to create an enormous empty array that has to get filled, despite me never using the contents.

Comment: @Rogare gotcha. I don't have a suggestion around that, but I'd warn against premature optimization and say keep looking for solutions only if you've witnessed real speed/storage issues.

Comment: Seconding @ConnorNeville. Just create one local trash variable and use it every time; 4 or 8 bytes of memory really shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks for the comment. For sure, I've been doing a trash variable in the enclosing scope (so it only needs to be created once), but just wondering if there was another way. That said, using generic memory instead that could be used by several of these functions could be a better idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Rogare: This is one of those times where using a global or something with a broader scope is probably just fine. Also remember that local integer variables are (I think) stack variables, so they stop using memory as soon as their scope is exited, and as such, even if you call some function that has a local trash variable a million times, you shouldn't end up using 4 million bytes of memory.

Comment: In what situation would you be ignoring an enormous array passed to vDSP? Most of the arguments you might want to ignore are scalars, so any memory occupied by them during the vDSP call and any time taken to fill the is trivial. Array parameters typically contain significant output, so you are unlikely to want to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Except for documented cases where a null argument is accepted, you must pass a valid address. There is no argument value that tells vDSP to ignore the argument.